# Login successfully but don't return value of webAuthenticationResult. How to fixt it,please?

Tags: c#, oauth, uwp

```
WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, new Uri(DropboxUrl), new Uri(callback_url));

if(webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus==WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
   {
      GetAccessToken(webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData);
   }
```

No error(login successfully),  but it did not return to( It stopped at  WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult= await)

```
webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus==WebAuthenticationStatus.Success
```

I don't understand. Before a few month, I had have used it normally.

**UPDATE**

```
{
            try
            {

                var SpotifyUrl = "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId) + "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("https://example/callback") + "&state=xyzbc&show_dialog=true";
                var StartUri = new Uri(SpotifyUrl);
                var EndUri = new Uri("https://example/callback");

                WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                        WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                        StartUri,
                                                        EndUri);
                if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
                {
                    var responseData = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData;

                    await GetSpotifyUserNameAsync(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString());
                }
                else if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
                {
                    throw new Exception("HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus.ToString());
                }

            }
```

Comment: I don't understand ... are you saying that `webAuthenticationResult` isn't set? Is there an exception? How would we reproduce this issue?

Comment: I login successfully.

Comment: I never get to the line 

if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)

Comment: my callback_url=https://xxx....
On internet: I saw everyone said "ms-app://xxx"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your `callbackUri` is as same as the redirect URI that you've used in your `DropboxUrl`.

Since you are using `DropboxUrl` in your code, I suppose you are using `WebAuthenticationBroker` to perform Dropbox authorization, the `DropboxUrl` would like this (see https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-authorize):

```
https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=<app key>&redirect_uri=<redirect URI>
```

As we are going to get the token, a redirect URI is required. We need to set it in [App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/apps). The redirect URI doesn't really matter as the broker never navigates to this URI, instead the broker returns the control back to the application. However we can use `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver` as the redirect URI. It's usually for client-side apps to use.

Then in `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync` method, we need to set the `callbackUri` same as the redirect URI. Because

> The callback URI that indicates the completion of the web authentication. The broker matches this URI against every URI that it is about to navigate to.

For more information, please see ***callbackUri*** in [`WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions, Uri, Uri)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212067.aspx) method.

And following is a simple sample:

```
public async Task<string> AuthorizeWithDropbox()
{
    var appKey = "<App Key>";

    var redirectUri = new Uri("https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver");

    var dropboxUri = new Uri($"https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&client_id={appKey}");
    var result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, dropboxUri, redirectUri);

    if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
    {
        return result.ResponseData;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The return value will like:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver#access_token=<token>&token_type=bearer&uid=<uid>
```

Comment: Hi @Jay Zuo: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/10342c45-2865-48bf-8960-ff260841784a/uwpmvvm-whats-problem-about-callbckurl?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I'm pretty sure is same

Comment: @sogo: What are the Dropbox URI and redirect URI you are using? I can't reproduce your issue in my side. Could you share your sample so that we can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Here is :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/10342c45-2865-48bf-8960-ff260841784a/uwpmvvm-whats-problem-about-callbckurl?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: @sogo: Glad to know you've solved your issue. In my sample, I'm using OAuth 2.0 to perform authorization. I think its a easy way to get access_token, you may have a try.

Comment: @@. You have code dropbox and vimeo. my vimeo is oauth2 but it still get error as dropbox.

Comment: Code vimeo on top page.

Comment: @sogo: I tested with your updated code. I can also get the `responseData` successfully. What's the error you've got? Besides, in [API Authentication on Vimeo on Vimeo Developer API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#generate-redirect), I didn't find `show_dialog`  field, you can delete it from your URI.

Comment: Oh my god. you are successfully, 
My code is no error but just don't return -> responseData. I don't understood. I'm getting mad.

Comment: Can you share your code successfully to msdn.microsoft...?

Comment: @sogo: I shared my repo at [GitHub](https://github.com/Z-Jay/AuthorizeWithVimeoTest), you can have a check.